# Is there a better way to block property overloading?

Tags: php, oop, overloading

```
<?php
class Item {
 public function __set($name, $value){
  throw new Exception('Overloading is forbidden.');
 }

 public function __get($name){
  throw new Exception('Overloading is forbidden.');
 }
}
```

I want to make sure I set all required object properties, but if I mistype a property name PHP just adds a new property and the prop I wanted to initialize remains null.

Comment: I want to make sure I set all required object properties, but if I mistype a property name PHP just adds a new property and the prop I wanted to initialize remains null.

Comment: Use an IDE that offers code completion and get in the habit of defining your properties with PHPDoc doc blocks, then it will list properties that match what you're typing... and it will be more obvious if you make a typo while you're actually typing. Better than adding a bit of execution overhead to prevent errors that should be trapped while you're developing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> I want to make sure I set all required object properties, but if I mistype a property name PHP just adds a new property and the prop I wanted to initialize remains null.

If you want to make sure you have set all required object properties, consider making them required arguments to the constructor, e.g.

```
class Item
{
    public function __construct($required, $alsoRequired, $moreRequired)
    {
        // assign to corresponding properties
    }
}
```

This way you can be sure the object is in valid state.

If you cannot set them at object creation, consider adding a validator method to your object. Call this method before doing any critical things with your object to make sure all required properties are set. This would be a much more useful addition to your API than implementing a typo safeguard.

In addition, you should not have an issue with this if you use proper setters. Access your object through an interface instead of assigning properties directly. If you mistype a method name, PHP will tell you (unless you implemented `__call`).

On a sidenote, `__get` and `__set` are not lazy replacements for proper Getters and Setters. They are interceptors that will be triggered when trying to access a non accessible property. This is much more related to error handling. Also note that they are much slower than proper Getter and Setter.

Comment: What if they're made `final`?

Comment: @BoltClock good catch. That would work. Removed that part of answer though after OP clarified what it is needed for.

Comment: I never use public properties in Java and always generate getters and setters, but I didn't realize that the solution is so simple because I didn't look at PHP from the object-oriented point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Just using the constructor will not solve the problem.
The problem he describes is very common and throwing an exception if __get or __set are called is a nice idea. 
If you want to, you can make those final but I see no reason why you should do this. Only classes that require dynamic propertys will override  the methods.
The only improvement I can suggest is enclosing the method definitions in
//*DEBUG
and
//*/
When you are finished debugging you can then easily run a replace(//*DEBUG with /*DEBUG) on all your code files and comment out __get and __set

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum. Please do not provide Comments to my answer as additional answer. There is an Add Comment button below my answer. Please provide your comment there and delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Using http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php you can check for existence of the variable and for example throw exception when fails